# In ACT-R difference between declarative and working memory

Tags: memory, cognitive-modeling, working-memory, act-r

I'm currently studying PRIMs within the context of ACT-R by reading these [two](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212683X14000206) [papers](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23750831). In the papers, there are references to both declarative and working memory modules of ACT-R. What is the difference between these memory modules? Is the only difference the allowed operations on this memory and thus their use? Are there also decay effects in working memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article](http://www.instructionaldesign.org/theories/act.html) explains the difference :

> **Declarative memory** takes the form of a semantic net linking
>   propositions, images, and sequences by associations.
>
> The nodes of long-term memory all have some degree of activation and
>   **working memory** is that part of long-term memory that is most highly
>   activated.

[image: ACT-R Model]

The declarative memory is all knowledge that can be retrieved in consciousness. Working memory activates only the declarative memory needed for the current task.

When a different task is given, the activation changes to match the needs of the new task. The non-relevant active knowledge is deactivated, and new relevant knowledge is retrieved.